# clustering using weka api

Tags: java, weka

I start cluster my data using open source code by using java + weka lib
it run correctly when the format of the dataset .arff but I want to use the dataset of movielens (to cluster the user using their demographic information )
the file name is "u.user"
you can find the file  dicription here
http://files.grouplens.org/datasets/movielens/ml-100k-README.txt

and this my code

```
import weka.clusterers.SimpleKMeans;
import weka.core.Instances;
import weka.core.converters.ConverterUtils.DataSource;
import java.io.IOException;
public class Clustering {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
        //load dataset
        String dataset = "C:/Users/DELL/Desktop/work/u.user";
        DataSource source = new DataSource(dataset);
        //get instances object
        Instances data = source.getDataSet();
        // new instance of clusterer
        SimpleKMeans model = new SimpleKMeans();//Simple EM (expectation maximisation)
        //number of clusters
        model.setNumClusters(4);
        //set distance function
        //model.setDistanceFunction(new weka.core.ManhattanDistance());
        // build the clusterer
        model.buildClusterer(data);
        System.out.println(model);

}
}
```

after the run this error display

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: File not found : C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\work\u.names
    weka.core.converters.C45Loader.setSource(C45Loader.java:190)
    weka.core.converters.AbstractFileLoader.setFile(AbstractFileLoader.java:90)
    weka.core.converters.ConverterUtils$DataSource.reset(ConverterUtils.java:306)
    weka.core.converters.ConverterUtils$DataSource.<init>(ConverterUtils.java:141)
    Clustering.main(Clustering.java:24)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)

    at weka.core.converters.C45Loader.setSource(C45Loader.java:190)
    at weka.core.converters.AbstractFileLoader.setFile(AbstractFileLoader.java:90)
    at weka.core.converters.ConverterUtils$DataSource.reset(ConverterUtils.java:306)
    at weka.core.converters.ConverterUtils$DataSource.<init>(ConverterUtils.java:141)
    at Clustering.main(Clustering.java:24)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I am sure it because the extention of  the file , beacause when I use other file with extention.arff it work
can you help me how to cluster my data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need to pay attention on the file format (not only the extension). Convert the dataset format to match [Weka ARFF format](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/arff.html). In case of your data `u.user`, you need to change the extension to *.arff (eg. `user.arff`) and the format to something like:

```
@RELATION user

@ATTRIBUTE id   INTEGER  % this is actually useless
@ATTRIBUTE age  INTEGER
@ATTRIBUTE gender   {M,F}
@ATTRIBUTE occupation   {administrator,artist,doctor,educator,engineer,entertainment,executive,healthcare,homemaker,lawyer,librarian,marketing,none,other,programmer,retired,salesman,scientist,student,technician,writer}  % from u.occupation
@ATTRIBUTE zipcode  STRING

@DATA
1,24,M,technician,85711
2,53,F,other,94043
3,23,M,writer,32067
4,24,M,technician,43537
5,33,F,other,15213
6,42,M,executive,98101
7,57,M,administrator,91344
8,36,M,administrator,05201
...
```

You should be able to parse the dataset into a `weka.core.Instances`. But, unfortunately, `SimpleKMeans` will reject your data with:

> weka.core.UnsupportedAttributeTypeException:
>   weka.clusterers.SimpleKMeans: Cannot handle string attributes!

So you are left with (at least) 3 options:

1. Vectorize or convert the features of your data to numeric values (also remove useless data like `id`)
2. Use another clustering algorithm that can handle categorical values such as `weka.clusterers.HierarchicalClusterer`
3. Combine both solution

Good luck!

Comment: (1) You don't need a program to do that. I converted the whole data in less than 5 minutes just using simply copy-paste & replace all. (2) Can you see any other `STRING` attribute other than `zipcode` in the definition? (3) If you are just expecting the code to run then you are fine. If you expect the data to be clustered properly then you aren't. This is post explains why https://www.quora.com/Why-in-categorical-data-k-means-clustering-is-weak

Comment: man thanks , you help me a lots 1- regarding the option one , how can to covert the features is there any code or tool for that ? 2-  and for option three can I just change this command  SimpleKMeans model = new SimpleKMeans(); with somthing for HierarchicalClusterer and the other step is the same or not

Comment: (1) There isn't any tool/code that can be directly used because the process will be unique for each dataset. One of the method that you can try is converting `zipcode` to nominal data type (like `occupation`) (2) You can. I'd suggest you try before asking next time

Comment: What I was trying to say, k-means is not suitable for categorical features (which are dominant in your data) as explained [here](http://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/22/k-means-clustering-for-mixed-numeric-and-categorical-data). But if you insist on using it you can convert the data by mapping them to reasonable number (eg. by removing leading zeros from zipcode 05201 -> 5201) and [normalize](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/29417/normalize-sample-data-for-clustering) them

Comment: Regarding the id, you can tell which cluster a user belongs to by passing the features of the user to the trained model.

Comment: Yes, you can run k-means clustering if the zipcode are removed. Why don‘t you just try code it and see?

Comment: Icould  not run the the dataset yet that is why I ask u I start with sample data and I wrote the arff format as you said  above in your question in cvs file the I use this website to covert cvs to arff  http://ikuz.eu/csv2arff/ but did not work , also I tried to wrote it in text file and change the extension also not work any solution

Comment: this is the exception java.io.IOException: Unable to determine structure as arff (Reason: java.io.IOException: } expected at end of enumeration, read Token[EOL], line 4).

Comment: That's why I suggested you to understand the arff & convert it manually. Anyway just try the file that I converted earlier (id & zipcode removed) http://pastebin.com/GHiw0q8z

Comment: thanks brother , I tried it  and this exception happened  java.io.IOException: No source has been specified
 at weka.core.converters.ArffLoader.getDataSet(ArffLoader.java:1226)
 at weka.core.converters.ConverterUtils$DataSource.getDataSet(ConverterUtils.java:268)

Comment: I didn't get such an exception in my code. What is your weka version? I'm using [stable 3.8.0](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/nz.ac.waikato.cms.weka/weka-stable/3.8.0)

Comment: yes the same version ,  I tried another . dataset  from internet with format (.arff )file and it work but  this file is not workof the file is ml-100k.user.arff  but the type of the file is actually (text document ) not a arff maybe this is the problem ? I am really confuse :(

Comment: arff is nothing but a text file with conventions. I have tried redownload it from pastebin, change the extension to .arff & ran it successfully. Can you pass me the link of the arff file that is working on your machine?

Comment: yes after download it is automatically name ml-100k.user.arff with no need to change anything , this is my dataset that I tried to test my code  and it work https://osdn.net/projects/sfnet_meka/downloads/Datasets/Other%20Datasets/MovieLens/movielens.arff/

Comment: I can also run the movielens.arff. Can you try to get the same file from here https://expirebox.com/download/5fc5f0c3a2e0b1847dcd391b691cff02.html ?

Comment: can you expline how did you save the file txt file as arff to do it next time

Comment: I didn't do anything special. I simply treat it like a text file. I suspect the problem is either with pastebin.com (as I notice few bytes off) or with your OS (windows)

Comment: thank you so next time if I want to generate arff file all I need is to write the format in notepad and then save it as .arff right ?